"ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported" error after run airflow scheduler
After i run airflow websever or airflow scheduler i faced this problem
I run in rhel7
class VARIANT_BOOL(_SimpleCData):
ValueError: type 'v' not supported
import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes
File "/home/quantri/lib/python3.7/ctypes/wintypes.py", line 23, in 
class VARIANT_BOOL(_SimpleCData):
ValueError: type 'v' not supported
Anyone can help me this problem pls
